# is it possible to use huawei 3g dongle in serial and network mode at the same time?

Tags: serial-port, usb-modem

I have a 3G dongle (huwaei e3531). 
when i plug it, it automatically switches to network mode (ethernet) which is good but i'm not able to access it in serial mode using putty, no usb device appears after

```
dmesg | grep ttyUSB
```

i want to be able to access it (to send sms using at commands) without losing 3g connection. i tried usb_modeswitch but it doesn't help.